# Send data to BroadcastReceiver (CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE) to access to database from it

Tags: android, email, broadcastreceiver, connectivity

I am programming a Geofence app. When user arrives at some point, geofence triggers, and sends a Mail. 
This works just perfect. But I need to control the case in which there is no connectivity so that the app sends the mail when connectivity becomes available.

I achieved this, with a Broadcast Receiver, which listens for CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE.

**My problem is** that I need to retrieve from database the details (receiver of the mail and text), and for that I need an "ID", but I can't find the way to pass this ID to the BroadcastReceiver.

This is my code:

I've an Intent that detects the Geofence, and if there is no Internet, activates the BroacasReceiver:

```
public class GeofenceIntentService extends IntentService implements com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

[...]

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);

    extras = intent.getExtras();

    Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(extras.getLong("id")));

    ID = extras.getLong("id");

  sendMail(ID);

    }
}

[...]

private void sendMail(long ID) {

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    cursor = dbHelper.getRegister(ID);

    dbHelper.close();


    tomail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tomail"));
    where = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("where"));
    texttosend = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("texttosend"));

    if (getConnectivityStatus(context) == 1 || getConnectivityStatus(context) == 2) {

                Mail m = new Mail("***", "****");

                String[] toArr = {tomail};
                m.setTo(toArr);
                m.setFrom("*****");
                m.setSubject(getString(R.string.justtrying));
                m.setBody(texttosend);


                try {

                    if (m.send()) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Email was sent successfully.");

                   } else {
                        Log.v(TAG, "Email was not sent.");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
                }
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Waiting for Internet Connection.");

          registerForBroadcasts(context);

            }
}

public void registerForBroadcasts(Context context) {
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context, NetworkChangeReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm1 = context.getPackageManager();
    pm1.setComponentEnabledSetting(
            component,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

An then the receiver on the manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:label="NetworkChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

As I said, this works, but then onReceive, I need to know the ID to get the contact info to send the mail. The Broadcast as an Intent variable, but I don't know how to edit it. This would be the idea:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    final Context mContext = context;

    String action = intent.getAction();
    extras = intent.getExtras();
    ID = extras.getLong("id");
```

Any ideas? The only alternative I can find is to keep checking for connectivity every 30secs, from the GeofenceIntent, but I think it would be much more effective to listen to Connectivity Change.

**EDIT:**
Finaly I solved this situation, by adding a "pending" column, on database, and from BroadcastReceiver checking all registers, where Pending = true.
Anyway I still have the doubt if there were any other way.